# Constants for CultureInfo Name

Tags: c#, .net, globalization

Is there a set of constants or an enumeration in C# system/globalization namespace which contains valid culture names?

I am looking for something so that I don't have to type in "en-GB", etc.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No there isn't.  The list of available cultures is system-specific - you can even register new custom cultures using [CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.aspx).

So if you want this, you'll have to create your own enum or constants for the subset of common cultures that you're interested in, e.g.:

```
public static class KnownCulture
{
    public readonly String EnglishUS = "en-US";
    public readonly String EnglishGB = "en-GB";
    ... etc ...
}
```

or

```
public enum KnownLCID
{
    EnglishUS = 0x409,
    EnglishGB = 0x809,
    ...
}
```

This is analogous to the `KnownColor` enumeration: it's not possible to create an enumeration for all possible colors, but it can make sense to have an enumeration for frequently used ones.

I wouldn't expect Microsoft to provide an equivalent `KnownCulture` enumeration out of the box, as it's rather sensitive (why is my culture not included?).

Comment: "I wouldn't expect Microsoft to provide an equivalent  KnownCulture enumeration out of the box," well there are iso standards, which java locale follows ...

Answer (score 21):

Yes, there is, [GetCultures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures.aspx):

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
```

That returns an array of `CultureInfo` objects, so if you want the string names you could use something like:

```
IEnumerable<CultureInfo> cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
string[] names = cultures.Select(c => c.Name).ToArray();
```

Note the "Culture Types" enum (from the MSDN link).  I suppose the most useful ones would be *NeutralCultures* and *SpecificCultures*.

> - **NeutralCultures**  Cultures that are associated with a language but are not specific to a country/region. The names of .NET Framework cultures consist of the lowercase two-letter code derived from ISO 639-1. For example: "en" (English) is a neutral culture.
>     Custom cultures can have any user-specified name, not just a two-letter code.
>     The invariant culture is included in the array of cultures returned by the CultureInfo.GetCultures method that specifies this value.
> - **SpecificCultures** Cultures that are specific to a country/region. The names of these cultures follow RFC 4646 (Windows Vista and later). The format is "-", where  is a lowercase two-letter code derived from ISO 639-1 and  is an uppercase two-letter code derived from ISO 3166. For example, "en-US" for English (United States) is a specific culture.
>     Custom cultures can have any user-specified name, not just a standard-compliant name.
> - **InstalledWin32Cultures**    All cultures that are installed in the Windows operating system. Note that not all cultures supported by the .NET Framework are installed in the operating system.
> - **AllCultures**   All cultures that ship with the .NET Framework, including neutral and specific cultures, cultures installed in the Windows operating system, and custom cultures created by the user.
> - **UserCustomCulture** Custom cultures created by the user.
> - **ReplacementCultures**   Custom cultures created by the user that replace cultures shipped with the .NET Framework.

Comment: This does not answer the question, as it does not expose `const`/`readonly` fields, nor an enumeration, and also does not prevent the OP from having to hardcode "en-GB".